# WebScraping A Table Doesn't Work With Python Beautiful Soup

Tags: python, web, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, python-requests

I am just starting with web scraping and want to try to scrape the table from this [site](https://www.nseindia.com/market-data/top-gainers-loosers) but when I start with finding the class of the table it doesn't work and instead shows `None`

Following Is My Code:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import json

url = 'https://www.nseindia.com/market-data/top-gainers-loosers'
headers = {'User-agent':'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_6) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/88.0.4324.192 Safari/537.36'}

r = requests.get(url,headers=headers)
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text,'html.parser')

table = soup.find('table',{'class':'customTable-widthCorp tableWidth-850 '})
print(table)
```

Following Is The Output Of The Code:
[Output Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ikYuV.png).

How Can I Scrape The Table Contents From The Site?

Comment: If the table in populated after page load via JavaScript, simple scraping won't be enough to get it, since you need to execute the JavaScript that loads the data. Selenium, or something else that executes JavaScript may be required. Open the Network tab in the Developer Tools in your browser, find the data that you're looking for, and see at what point it's loaded.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You get the data through the api. Looping through you can get each of the different tables for both gainers and loosers (it actually should be "losers", but that's another issue):

```
import requests
import json
import pandas as pd

s = requests.Session()

url = 'https://www.nseindia.com/api/live-analysis-variations'
headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/88.0.4324.190 Safari/537.36'}
s.get('https://www.nseindia.com/market-data/top-gainers-loosers', headers=headers)

data = {}
for index in ['gainers', 'loosers']:
    headers['Referer'] = 'https://www.nseindia.com/market-data/top-gainers-loosers'
    payload = {'index':index}

    jsonStr = s.get(url, headers=headers, params=payload).text
    jsonData = json.loads(jsonStr)
    data[index] = jsonData

table = {}
for k, v in data.items():
    table[k] = {}
    for each_k, each_v in v.items():
        if type(each_v) == dict:
            temp_df = pd.DataFrame(each_v['data'])
            table[k][each_k] = temp_df
```

So you get a nice like key:value structure here where you can call on the key `'gainers'` or `'loosers'`, then the specific table:

[image]

**Output:**

```
print(table['gainers']['NIFTY'])
        symbol series  open_price  high_price  low_price      ltp  prev_price  \
0     JSWSTEEL     EQ      470.55      512.95     470.00   505.50      468.45   
1     HINDALCO     EQ      329.75      352.00     328.45   348.30      326.85   
2    TATASTEEL     EQ      821.00      868.90     819.00   858.90      811.85   
3   ADANIPORTS     EQ      713.50      742.00     705.00   733.55      702.40   
4   INDUSINDBK     EQ      964.00      997.00     959.10   996.00      954.45   
5    KOTAKBANK     EQ     1770.00     1813.25    1750.65  1804.00     1753.00   
6         BPCL     EQ      430.60      439.95     428.05   438.00      427.95   
7    ICICIBANK     EQ      587.55      596.10     580.20   594.75      582.10   
8   ULTRACEMCO     EQ     6766.00     6933.70    6731.20  6882.00     6737.95   
9     AXISBANK     EQ      706.30      717.00     695.55   711.95      697.45   
10   SUNPHARMA     EQ      600.00      612.70     597.35   610.00      597.80   
11  BAJFINANCE     EQ     5210.00     5288.50    5161.95  5255.00     5149.85   
12        ONGC     EQ      103.00      105.25     101.15   104.20      102.15   
13         UPL     EQ      640.95      656.90     635.00   654.30      641.85   
14  BAJAJ-AUTO     EQ     3704.00     3764.30    3690.20  3740.00     3670.60   
15        SBIN     EQ      367.70      371.90     363.10   370.95      364.30   
16     HCLTECH     EQ      992.00     1013.50     990.60  1000.60      982.65   
17  TATAMOTORS     EQ      306.75      309.85     303.05   307.25      301.80   
18  TATACONSUM     EQ      641.00      652.95     640.65   650.10      638.90   
19          LT     EQ     1432.00     1447.85    1420.50  1442.00     1418.90   

    net_price  trade_quantity       turnover market_type     ca_ex_dt  \
0        7.91        35736230  177737.713528           N  06-Jul-2020   
1        6.56        25631843   88037.691152           N  03-Sep-2020   
2        5.80        36842098  310298.886195           N  06-Aug-2020   
3        4.43        15017049  108975.721183           N  17-Jun-2020   
4        4.35         7932671   77319.744237           N  08-Aug-2019   
5        2.91         3802652   67696.712230           N  12-Jul-2019   
6        2.35         4578197   19829.086846           N  25-Mar-2021   
7        2.17        15631940   91786.062098           N  22-Jul-2019   
8        2.14          531749   36393.805533           N  29-Jul-2020   
9        2.08        13090326   92479.226092           N  04-Jul-2019   
10       2.04         6033653   36518.684783           N  09-Feb-2021   
11       2.04         2148234  111995.816533           N  03-Mar-2020   
12       2.01        22299747   22973.199359           N  17-Feb-2021   
13       1.94         7348750   47452.348500           N  19-Aug-2020   
14       1.89          861229   32221.246700           N  03-Mar-2020   
15       1.83        31883453  117034.590927           N  15-Jun-2018   
16       1.83         5269079   52919.994936           N  21-Jan-2021   
17       1.81        44088352  135033.804506           N  18-Jul-2016   
18       1.75         3844057   24900.648029           N  18-Jun-2020   
19       1.63         1380763   19812.430211           N  04-Nov-2020   

                                           ca_purpose  perChange  
0                           Dividend - Rs 2 Per Share       7.91  
1    Annual General Meeting/Dividend - Re 1 Per Share       6.56  
2                          Dividend - Rs 10 Per Share       5.80  
3                              Annual General Meeting       4.43  
4   Annual General Meeting/Dividend - Rs 7.50 Per ...       4.35  
5   Annual General Meeting/Dividend Rs 0.80 Per Share       2.91  
6                   Interim Dividend - Rs 5 Per Share       2.35  
7    Annual General Meeting/Dividend - Re 1 Per Share       2.17  
8   Annual General Meeting/Dividend - Rs 13 Per Share       2.14  
9   Annual General Meeting/ Dividend - Re 1 Per Share       2.08  
10               Interim Dividend - Rs 5.50 Per Share       2.04  
11                 Interim Dividend - Rs 10 Per Share       2.04  
12               Interim Dividend - Rs 1.75 Per Share       2.01  
13                             Dividend - Rs 6 Per Sh       1.94  
14                Interim Dividend - Rs 120 Per Share       1.89  
15  Annual General Meeting/ Change In Registrar An...       1.83  
16                  Interim Dividend - Rs 4 Per Share       1.83  
17                     Dividend - Re 0.20/- Per Share       1.81  
18  Annual General Meeting/Dividend -Rs 2.70 Per S...       1.75  
19                 Special Dividend - Rs 18 Per Share       1.63  


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/djz5A.png
```

Comment: Did that keep working for you with repeated runs? I ran something similar.

Comment: No, had that issue as well. So I added `s = requests.Session()` and then it was fine.

Comment: Yeah thought it was a cookie thing. +

Comment: @QHarr, same here, but didn't see any cookies in the request headers which I thought was weird.

Comment: Well How Can I Get Specific Values From The Above ? Like I want all the stocks and their lip and their change and store it as a dictionary or a python list ?

Comment: Well the 'data' variable here is python lists/dictionaries. So work off that

Comment: @chitown88 Also I want % chng which not in the your program but your code just works fine massive thanks for writing this code really helps me out.

Comment: Is the “perChange” column not % change?

Comment: Yeah It Is I Completely Didn't Looked At It

Answer (score 2):

Data can be obtained from an API call. If you examine the javascript function that is called you for the csv download you can set the generate the url and call it.

Can't immediately see a way to download without involving a browser so you could just paste the url into e.g. Chrome and it will download, or automate with selenium and driver.get to the url. With requests I think you need to dynamically set a cookie in the header.

url is

[https://www.nseindia.com/api/live-analysis-variations?index=gainers&type=NIFTY&csv=true'](https://www.nseindia.com/api/live-analysis-variations?index=gainers&type=NIFTY&csv=true%27))

Comment: Is There any way to without involving any browser and also If I changed the api call to this [https://www.nseindia.com/api/live-analysis-variations?index=gainers&type=NIFTY&json=true] it returns the content in json format any ideas of how can I get this data in to python?

Comment: I think you need to pick up a dynamic cookie and pass that in headers with requests. However, I am not yet sure if one gets blocked for a period as I had a working version which no longer runs.